# Threading sync clarifcation

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronization

Just want to be sure I understand locking

```
public class MySync {
    public static synchronized byte[] getRes(String str1, String str2) throws Exception {
        ...
        return new byte[myLen];
    }
    //no other methods
}
public class MyClass extends MyClass2 {
    public MyStuff getStuff (SomeObj obj)   {
        byte[] res =  MySync.getRes(s1,s2);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Thread 1 calls MyClass
Thread 2 calls MyClass
Thread 3 calls MyClass
T1 calls getres.
T2 waits for T1 to finish with its lock on MySync class
T3 waits for T1 to finish with its lock on MySync class
T1 finishes
T3 calls getres (i.e. order is/is not preserved?)
T2 waits for T3 to finish
T3 finishes
T2 calls getres

yes?

getRes is now "bottleneck"; threads need to wait in "queue"? 
Note, I do want this for my application. Only one thread permitted per operation.

The below would accomplish the same as above, except lock is on myLock class?
It is preferred, why?

```
public class MySync {
    private static final Object myLock = new Object();
public byte[] getRes(String str1, String str2) throws Exception {
        synchronized (myLock) {
            ...
                return new byte[myLen];
        }

public class MyClass extends MyClass2 {
public MyStuff getStuff (SomeObj obj)   {
    byte[] res =  new MySync().getRes(s1,s2);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not exactly right, the thread that next acquires the lock after 1 is random. It could be _either_ 2 or 3.

Comment: `getRes` sounds like you are reading some shared resource. If you are only _reading_ it there is no need to lock. Locking is necessary only if you _modify_ a shared resource (shared meaning - shared by multiple threads). If you are modifying it in some other method then make sure both methods lock on the same lock object.

Answer (score 3):

In case of

```
public static synchronized byte[] getRes(String str1, String str2)
```

the implicit lock will be the `class` instance which is `MySync.class` (since its a static synchronized method). So yes, you are right, its **mutually exclusive**.

In case of

```
public class MySync {
    private static final Object myLock = new Object();
public byte[] getRes(String str1, String str2) throws Exception {
        synchronized (myLock) {
```

the result is same, because your lock `myLock` is `static` and its **shared** across multiple instances of your `MySync` class

Below method is preferred because the `MySync.class` object will not have overhead of getting locked/unlocked by threads, instead there is a dedicated `myLock` object

As mentioned in the comment by @BoristheSpider, [Lock objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) introduced by Java5 gives the programmer much more flexibility in managing locks on a method/block and it is also more readable.

Comment: You may want to mention that using an lock `Object` as a lock is deprecated since [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) was introduced in java 5.

Comment: Synchronized blocks are not deprecated.  Why do you think that?

Answer (score 0):

The order of threads acquiring the lock is random in case of `synchronize`.

You can use a [lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) to dictate the order though.

Also, in case 1 the lock is over the entire `Class object` in latter case its just over the `lock`.